# Mixed strategy equilibrium in Cournot Duopoly

Tags: game-theory, economics, infinite-games

This maybe a trivial question to most. I am fairly new to game theory.

The usual cournot duopoly (same constant marginal cost for both players) is solved using pure strategies. Are there mixed strategy solutions also? If not, is it obvious or is that solving would give p=1 for the pure strategy solution? What's the economic logic for (not) having mixed strategy equilibria?

**EDIT:**
Let there be two players $A$ and $B$ who produce, respectively, $q_a$ and $q_b$ quantities of the same good. The market price of the good is determined by the inverse demand function:
$P=\alpha - \beta q$; where $q\equiv q_a + q_b$. The marginal cost of production is $c$ for both $A$ and $B$.

So the profit function is: $\pi_i=Pq_i-cq_i$; $\forall i=a,b$

The best response function, $R_i(q_j)$ is obtained by $\partial \pi_i/ \partial q_i=0$

The pure strategy equilibrium is intersection point of the two response functions.

Comment: Can you include details of the Cournot model in your question?

Comment: Edited to include a simple cournot duopoly model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to show that a best-response of player $i\in\{A,B\}$ to any mixed strategy by player $j, j\neq i$ is a pure-best response. This implies that there cannot be a mixed strategy NE.

---

To see this, suppose that player $j$ uses a mixed strategy described by a distribution $F$, that is $q_j\sim F$, such that $\mathbb{E}(q_j)$ exists. Let $\bar{q}_j \equiv\mathbb{E}(q_j)$. Then, the problem of player $i$, $i\neq j$, is given by:

$$ max_{q_i} [(\alpha-\beta \mathbb{E}(q)] q_i - cq_i) $$

But, $\mathbb{E}(q)=q_i+\bar{q}_j$ and so the F.O.C. to the above problem is 
$$  \alpha - \beta(2q_i+\bar{q}_j)-c=0$$

Rearranging, we obtain
$$ q_i = \frac{\alpha-\beta \bar{q}_j-c}{2\beta}$$

From this equation, we see that there is a unique quantity $q_i$ that is the best-response to player $j's$ mixed-strategy. It follows that players will always use pure-strategies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can we interpet this result like this: for mixed strategy equilibria to exist, there should be an $F$ over $q_j$ such that the expected profit for player $i$ is same regardless of what $q_i$ she chooses (i.e. she is indifferent to all the possible actions in her action space). Since this is clearly not possible here, there is no mixed strategy solution.

Comment: Almost. A necessary condition for the existence of an equilibrium in  mixed strategies is that if player $j$ uses mixed strategies then, at least sometimes, there are at least two pure responses that provide the same payoff to player $i$ and so he is willing to mix himself. So player $i$ doesn't have to be indifferent between all possible $q_i$, but has to be indifferent between at least two.

Comment: Oh yes of course! The support does not necessarily have to be the entire action set. Thanks a lot. I realized that the profit fuction for player $i$ is one-to-one in $q_i$. So no mixed strategy solutions. Thanks again.